# Help with geometrical interpretations of symmetric positive-definite 2nd rank tensor

Tags: linear-algebra

If
$$\tag{1} S=S_{ij}l_il_j$$
and
$$\tag{2} a_i=S_{ij}b_j$$
we can find the geometrical relation between $S, a_i,$ and $b_i$, while taking $l_i$ and $b_i$ to be co-linear, through the following manipulation:
$$\tag{3} S=S_{ij}l_il_j=\frac{S_{ij}l_il_j|b_i||b_i|}{|b_i|^2}=\frac{S_{ij}b_ib_j}{|b_i|^2}=\frac{a_ib_i}{|b_i|^2}=\frac{|a_i||b_i|\cos \theta}{|b_i|^2}=\frac{|a_i|\cos \theta}{|b_i|}$$

Thus from Eqn(3) we see that the magnitude $S$ characterizing the symmetric positive-definite 2nd-rank tensor in a given direction is the ratio of the projection of vector $a_i$ onto this direction to the length (magnitude) of vector $b_i$ laid off (oriented) in the same direction. $\theta$ is the angle between vectors $a_i$ and $b_i$.

**But what if we take $l_i$ and $a_i$ to be co-linear, instead, in the development of Eqn(3)? When taking $l_i$ and $a_i$ to be co-linear, can $S$ be defined in terms of $a_i, b_i, \theta$ only, or perhaps without the term $S_{ij}$?**

For answers: explicit steps/intermediate manipulations with explanation are greatly appreciated.